# Error when trying to display image from my database on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to display an image saved in the database but this error occurs when executed:

Failed to detect image file format using the file header.
File header was [0x5b 0x31 0x30 0x30 0x2c 0x20 0x39 0x37 0x2c 0x20].
Image source: encoded image bytes

This is where I get and convert the image:

```
final String imageString = data['image']['data'].toString();
final List<int> list = imageString.codeUnits;
image = Uint8List.fromList(list);
```

And here is where i try to display it on my tree:

```
 Image(
      image: MemoryImage(image),
      width: 165,
      height: 165,
 ),
```

Comment: what does `imageString ` represent? is it a base64 encoded image? is it the bytes of the image saved as string and separated by whitespaces? you need to give more information.

Comment: imageString are the bytes of the image saved as String, sorry, forgot to give that information. In the the database it is saved as 0x64154988541D and so on, when I do the get request, sequelize translates it to [100,97,116,97,58,105,109,97,103,101,47,106...] and so on. When I try to convert that to a Uint8List it gives the error above.